# Remove hyper reference (back reference) in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, back-referencing

I'm having a trouble with removing the hyperlinks that LaTeX generates after each bibliographic entry.

Example:

> A. Jonas, J. App. Chem, 2000,
>   **1,5,8,13,15,17**

The numbers "1,5,8,..." are in fact the pages on which I refer to this reference. 
The template that I use includes the `hyperref` package. I have disabled this package (inserted a `%`) but still, there is no change. 
I am sure that the trouble comes from the main .tex file (and not from the class file that I use for the bibliography, because I tried different classes, and I still get the page numbers.)

Summary: **I want to disable hyperlinks in my bibliography (or in my whole text). Although I commented out the `hyperref` package, it doesn't work.**

It would be great if you could help me. I have to submit my thesis the day after tomorrow!!!

Comment: post your preamble, please.

Comment: The `backref` package will add these links, as will the `backref` option to `hyperref`. Something is loading one of these packages. Without seeing your preamble it's hard to say much else.

Comment: @Lev-Bishop, Why don't you post your comment as an answer, @saghi probably submitted his thesis and does'nt seem to be following this question anymore...

Comment: With no feedback, and no preamble, we can't hope to answer this. I've therefore closed 'too localized'.

Answer (score 4):

The backref package will add these links, as will the backref option to hyperref. Something is loading one of these packages. Without seeing your preamble it's hard to say much else.